# WinForm CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I just tried to install `CefSharp` on a new `winForm` application, i install the latest version with Nuget and done all the steps by this article:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application

```
Running on : "Any CPU"
Visual Studio 2013
CefSharp 69.0.0
```

When i run the application i get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

This is the code:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Any idea what is the problem?

**EDIT**
This is the app.config file of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="x86"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does the file exist in the startup directory of the process you're running (and/or the build output)? I've had some NuGet problems where the CefSharp files get deleted post-compilation.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Where is the startup directory? Because i just try to run it from the VS2013

Comment: It'll be the folder that contains the executables for your project, e.g. (myproject.)\bin\debug - where (myproject) is where the .csproj file is.

Comment: The official instructions for `AnyCPU` support are https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714
A working example is available at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/demo/anycpu

Comment: @amaitland I tried all the info from the post and  keep getting this error. the example project working but it work with 63.0 and not 69.0.,also i noticed that only `CefSharp.Core.dll` is not loaded but `CefSharp.WinForms.dll` loaded perfectly

Comment: Upgrade the branch to the latest version and see what you get, there are three any cpu demo branches,  pick the one that closest suites your requirements.

Comment: I have updated https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/demo/anycpu to 71.0.0-pre01 and it works as expected. Double then triple check your code.

Comment: @amaitland same issue, The dll exist in this path `Telegram\Telegram\bin\Debug\x64\` but still get this error.

Comment: Does the `MinimalExample` work?

Comment: You saying `Same Issue` is not particularly helpful, it doesn't provide me with any information.

Comment: Also the `privatePath="x86"` is set to `x86` and you claim to be using `x64` according to the folder. Please edit your post and include all the code relevant to what you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case this happened when we failed to install the Visual C++ runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In app.config file , please check dependentAssembly segment for CelfSharp.
If it has any entry, make sure that the version of added reference be in valid range.

Comment: I just update my Question with the app.config file content, i can't see there anything about the CefSharp